# Mapbox failed to read the storage key

Tags: mapbox

I have the storage key but mapbox is still saying

```
E/Mbgl-FileSource: Failed to read the storage key: 
                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
                       at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource.getCachePath(FileSource.java:88)
                       at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource$FileDirsPathsTask.doInBackground(FileSource.java:165)
                       at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource$FileDirsPathsTask.doInBackground(FileSource.java:155)
                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also get the error when calling `MapView.onStart()`.

Is it because Im using free token?

Also, My key is being printed when calling `Log.d("app", Mapbox.getAccessToken());`

My other problem is that when I starting the navigation using this code:

```
NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder().origin(origin).destination(dest).shouldSimulateRoute(true).build();
        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(this, options);
```

The map in Navigation won't show, Its just a blue blank background with its UI, maybe its because the key cannot be read. But it can't be a reason because `Mapbox.getAccessToken()` is returning my correct token. I am really confused now.

Comment: Do you have your MainActivity.java code? It could be usefull to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Alex the stacktrace actually comes from nowhere. it doesnt give me which line of my code emits the error and the 2nd time the error appears is when i call `onStart()` https://pastebin.com/7t7fdtW0

Comment: Any luck with this? Having the same issue as well...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the exact same error and for me it turned out to be that I was not setting the content view before trying to find my map view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```